# Rotating drawable that will be used as marker icon in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-maps, android-drawable

I want to add markers to the map (api v2) from a drawable currently I do it like this :

```
mMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin))));
```

Now I want to rotate the drawable before I use it as a marker icon. What is the best way to do it ?
I tried

```
Bitmap bmpOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.pin);
        Bitmap bmResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(bmResult); 
        tempCanvas.rotate((float)answer.getPoints().get(i).getAzimut(), bmpOriginal.getWidth()/2, bmpOriginal.getHeight()/2);
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, null);
        mMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ll).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmResult))));
```

But the resulting drawable is strangely deformed. I think there must be a better and cleaner solution.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Well I can't remmber. It was an old project years ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32943568/1039935