# How to change distance between marker and infowindow in googlemaps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In my design I have a distance between marker and info window. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image: pic]

EDIT: My question is how to move info window a little bit up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found answer here: [Android Google Map InfoWindow anchor point after marker rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943568/android-google-map-infowindow-anchor-point-after-marker-rotation)

You can find point of the middle of the top of your marker with this code:

```
var angle = 0.0;
var x = Math.sin(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * 0.5 + 0.5;
var y = -(Math.cos(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * 0.5 - 0.5);
```

and set some offset. In my case -0.1f:

```
marker.setInfoWindowAnchor((float)x, (float)y -0.1f); // -0.1f for moving up
```