# Rotating GoogleMaps InfoWindow anchor point

Tags: android, google-maps

When a GoogleMaps marker is rotated, I would like to move the anchor point of the InfoWindow to always be at the bottom, but offset by a larger amount than the size of the marker itself.

I made a drawing to describe my problem, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to upload an image.

*Edit - this link hopefully works: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM9nc.png
The code below works for Point B.
I want to move to Point C*

This code (found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943568/android-google-map-infowindow-anchor-point-after-marker-rotation/32947599#32947599)) works well moving the anchor point to the top [0.5, 0]:

```js
var angle = 130.0;
var x = Math.sin(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * 0.5 + 0.5;
var y = -(Math.cos(-angle * Math.PI / 180) * 0.5 - 0.5);
marker.setInfoWindowAnchor((float)x, (float)y);
```

However I have not been successful in adjusting it for a point located beyond the bottom, at [0.5,1.5].

I think this is because the x and the y offsets are different sizes.

NB Info Window anchor points can be beyond the 0,0 - 1,1 range, I'm just struggling to make the mathematical calculation

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: i would use `android.graphics.Matrix` API and its `mapPoints` method

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into the mapPoints method. However, I would still like to know what the mathematical solution is