# How to set marker title text size in google map in swift 5

Tags: swift, google-maps

I have used google map in swift 5. I have used icon with marker title. But my marker title cover over the icon. Marker icon does not clearly shows. My icon move every 10 second. I have also used rotation for marker.when rotation left or right, marker titl covers my icon. here is screen shot
[image]
here is code bellow..

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.title = "D M Th 13-6573"
marker.icon = UIImage(named: "item_car_slow")
marker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(heading)
marker.map =  self.googleMap
self.googleMap.selectedMarker = marker
```

Please help me

Comment: can you add a screen shot of the error you are facing?

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I have added screenshot

Comment: Can you try the following solution to see if it helps?

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I have tried marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5) but same

Comment: try setting y to 1.0

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar same issue

Comment: can you show how does it look with out the info window??

Comment: and also what is the value of heading in the case when there is this UI error

Comment: let me know about above 2 so can check accordingly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206231/discussion-between-harshal-bhavsar-and-enamul-haque).

Comment: hello You there please check the updated answer it should solve your issue. tested locally on my side works fine

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar thanks you sir you have given a lot of time

Comment: @EnamulHaque i am happy that was able to help you and also learn something new. Thanks to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey after searching a bit more about the problem, I can firmly say that it's happening when the rotation is applied and then the `infoWindowAnchor` is not correct.

So what you have to do here is Calculate the `infoWindowAnchor` based on the angle as follows

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.title = "D M Th 13-6573"
marker.icon = UIImage(named: "item_car_slow")
marker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(heading)
marker.map =  self.googleMap
marker.infoWindowAnchor = getInfoWindowAnchorFor(heading)
self.googleMap.selectedMarker = marker
```

Following function will calculate the the correct anchor point.

```
func getInfoWindowAnchorFor(_ angle: Double) -> CGPoint {
    let x = sin(-angle * Double.pi / 180) * 0.5 + 0.5
    let y = -(cos(-angle * Double.pi / 180) * 0.5 - 0.5)
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

Note the above logic is take from this answer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32947599/5332817) on a old question for android SDK. For details on the logic and calculation please visit the original answer.

This should solve your problem.

Happy Coding